# R: How do I copy a value from a table and paste it into all rows within a specified row number range?

Tags: r, datatable

The current issue I am facing is that I have generated a list of row numbers based on the location of specific values within a table. This is as follows:

```
row_values <- which(table[,1] == "place of work :")
```

This leaves me with a list of all the row numbers in which "place of work" appears:

```
[1]     1   406   811  1216  1621  2026  2431  2836  3241  3646  4051  4456  4861  5266  5671  6076  6481  6886  7291  7696  8101  8506  8911  9316  9721 10126
[27] 10531 10936 11341 11746 12151 12556
```

This is 32 entries in total. I then also have another table which contains a number of codes (32 in total):

```
Area Code (Origin)
 [1,] "E41000293"       
 [2,] "E41000294"       
 [3,] "E41000295"       
 [4,] "E41000296"       
 [5,] "E41000297"       
 [6,] "E41000298"       
 [7,] "E41000299"       
 [8,] "E41000300"       
 [9,] "E41000301"       
[10,] "E41000302"       
[11,] "E41000303"       
[12,] "E41000304"       
[13,] "E41000305"       
[14,] "E41000306"       
[15,] "E41000307"       
[16,] "E41000308"       
[17,] "E41000309"       
[18,] "E41000310"       
[19,] "E41000311"       
[20,] "E41000312"       
[21,] "E41000313"       
[22,] "E41000314"       
[23,] "E41000315"       
[24,] "E41000316"       
[25,] "E41000317"       
[26,] "E41000318"       
[27,] "E41000319"       
[28,] "E41000320"       
[29,] "E41000321"       
[30,] "E41000322"       
[31,] "E41000323"       
[32,] "E41000324"
```

I need to find a way to paste those "Area Code (Origin)" values into the original table in every row between what the row_values as shown. These would sit in a blank column I have called "Area Codes (Destinations)". I.e, E41000293 should sit in the Area Code Destinations Column for every row from 1 to 405, E41000294 should sit from 406 to 810 ect.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss for how best to approach this.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
for (i in 1:length(row_values)) {
  
  if (i == length(row_values)-1) {
    table[c(row_values[i]:(row_values[i+1])),'Area Codes (Destinations)'] = Areacode[i]
  }  else if (i <length(row_values)-1)) {
    table[c(row_values[i]:(row_values[i+1]-1)),'Area Codes (Destinations)'] = Areacode[i]
  }else{}
}
```

Comment: Worked a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cumsum` in a clever way to achieve this:

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(text == "place of work :")) %>% #change "text" to your column name
  mutate(Area_Code = Area[grp,]) %>% #change Area to your table name
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

All that's left to do is change the table names and column names to fit your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this response buddy. I am unfamiliar with this method so I have picked another answer as I can personally work through that one and understand the functionality a bit better. Yet, after playing around with this, this does work well as well! I'll be sure to look into understanding this a bit better over the next few days :)

Comment: To give you a little head start: The cumsum counts how many times the string has been found in your column from row 1 till the current row. This means that from row 1 until row 405 there has been 1 occurrence of your string. These 405 rows will all be listed as "1". Then I replace that 1 by the value in your second table that has row number 1. For row 406 till 810 where there have been 2 occurrences (1 and 406) of your string I replace the 2 by the value in your second table that has row number 2. etc. The ungrouping and selecting is just clean-up duty.